# Amazon awscli tool --data-set-publication-date is not limiting rows by publication date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I think I found a bug with the awscli bash command line interface, specifically with the `--data-set-publication-date` flag.

Here is the bash command I use:

```
aws marketplacecommerceanalytics generate-data-set 
  --data-set-type customer_subscriber_hourly_monthly_subscriptions 
  --data-set-publication-date 12/01/2016 
  --role-name-arn "arn:aws:iam::431111111153:role/MarketplaceCommerceAnalyticsRole" 
  --destination-s3-bucket-name "marketplacecommerceanalytics" 
  --destination-s3-prefix test 
  --sns-topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:412341234123:marketplacecommerceanalytics"
```

Specifying a timestamp and passing it to the data-set-publication-date parameter does not cause it to return data on that date.  It returns the same set of data every time, it appears to be the most recent available data.

The following webpage defines the correct usage of the flag:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/marketplacecommerceanalytics/generate-data-set.html

I've tried many different formats for date as well as tried escaping special characters and surrounding it in quotes.  Nothing seems to cause it to filter the output based on date.

**Date formats I tried:**

```
2016-01-01
2016/01/01
"2016/01/01"

01-01-2016
01/01/2016
"01/01/2016"

2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
2016/01/01T00:00:00Z
"2016/01/01T00:00:00Z"

01-01-2016T00:00:00Z
01/01/2016T00:00:00Z
"01/01/2016T00:00:00Z"
```

When I send in a malformed timestamp like `asdf` or `1-2-3-4`, I will get an error stating that the timestamp is malformed, indicating that it is at least acknowledging receipt of the date.  However when it is correctly formed, there is no response and the data I get back is not limited by publication date.

Comment: One assumes the date would be specified in a standard [iso8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, e.g. `2016-12-01`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I tried all the formats.  2016-12-01 both quoted and unquoted.  I edited the post to show you what dates I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question in the AWS Marketplace Commerce Analytics Service Onboarding and Technical Guide:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsmp-loadforms/AWS-Marketplace-Commerce-Analytics-Service-Onboarding-and-Technical-Guide.pdf

Down on page 16 through 20 there are examples which specify the type of date you need to pass in:

```
--data-set-publication-date "2016-04-21T00:00:00Z"
```

What had tripped me up was that it doesn't return the exact date range of values you specify, but instead a list of all the active subscribers up to that moment, which from day to day changes.  So if I request for 01/01/2016, and then wait and request: 01/02/2016, there will be overlapped rows on the second request to the first request, new rows in the second request not in the first, and missing rows in the second request that are in the first.

I assumed it was a bug because it returned dupes from different days, but that's how it communicates created_date and end_date without giving you that data.